# How to Disable Shortkeys on ComboBox In C# using Windows Application?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, keyboard-shortcuts

In Main Form i have Short Cut Keys(ctrl + S ) for saving the data in DataBase. For combobox (ctrl + Alphabets) is the default Operation. How can I disable shortcut keys for Combobox?

UPDATE:

On keyPress event we can Do this

```
        if (ModifierKeys == Keys.Control)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
```

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/61600ac7-0ec6-47a6-801e-54d8aea2689e/disable-shortcut-key-f4-into-combobox

Answer (score 4):

You can try overriding ProcessCmdKey method of the Main Form:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) {
  const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100; 

  if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.S)) {
    if (msg.Msg == WM_KEYDOWN)
      MySaveDataToDatabase(); // <- Do your save command

    return true; // <- Stop processing the WM_KeyDown message for Ctrl + S (and shortcut as well)
  }

  // All other key messages process as usual
  return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I get the feeling that your problem is actually that the combobox is getting keypresses before your form. Be sure to set the Form's KeyPreview property to true if you want to handle keypresses before your controls.

More information about the KeyPreview property:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview(v=vs.100).aspx

If you are getting issues like overriding the F4 key (which in a combobox shows all options available by default), note the bit about setting the KeyPressEventArgs.Handled property in the form's KeyPress event handler to true.

Answer (score 0):

For most hot keys you can override the PreviewKeyDown event specify what to allow or not, eg:

```
void comboBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   var keysToIgnore = new []{
       Keys.S,
       Keys.X,
       Keys.F4,
       Keys.Space,
   }.ToList();

   if (keysToIgnore.Contains(e.KeyCode)) {
      if(e.Modifiers == Keys.Alt) ; // Do stuff (or don't) here
   }
}
```

There's all sorts of ways you can structure your logic depending on what your actual use case is but hopefully you get the idea.

You might find some hot key combinations aren't possible to disable this way, in which case you'll need to use the Win32API: `UnregisterHotKey`. More info here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646327%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

The main advantage of using the PreviewKeyDown event is you can also easily replace behaviour instead of just disabling it. The main advantage of using UnregisterHotKey is it operates at a lower level and is a far more robust and reliable way of disabling hot keys.

EDIT:

If you need to get a contiguous range of values you can try something like:

```
int keyCode = (int) (e.KeyCode);
if(keyCode >= (int)(Keys.A) && keyCode <= (int)(Keys.Z)) { /* do stuff */ }
```

but again, an ideal solution really depends on the specifics of your use case. There's no generic 'right answer'.

Comment: There is no key property in PreviewKeyDown

Comment: Thanks, have fixed it. It should be `KeyCode` not `Key`.

Comment: then For all alphabets how can you do that.

Comment: Have added example with multiple items. If you require all possible keys, don't use a KeyCode test at all. If you require all letters or numbers for example, you'll either have to declare them all somewhere (like in the above example). There's no (clean) way around it.